# Matrix exponentiation problem

Tags: matrices

I have a problem with figuring this out. I looked at [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential), but I'm not understanding it obviously. I have a matrix

$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&a\\a&0\end{array}\right)
$$

And I need to find matrix exponential of that matrix. The solution is given as:

$$
\exp\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&a\\a&0\end{array}\right)=\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{1}{k!}\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&a\\a&0\end{array}\right)^k=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&a\\a&0\end{array}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{cc}a^2&0\\0&a^2\end{array}\right)+\frac{1}{6}\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&a^3\\a^3&0\end{array}\right)+\ldots
$$

But how? Shouldn't it be just writing a Taylor expansion for exponential function with $A$ as exponent? Why are the terms alternating? Can someone clarify this a bit for me? Thanks.

Comment: Calculate $A^2$ by hand and you will see why the terms alternate like that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiply out a few and you will see:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&a\\a&0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&a\\a&0\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}a^2&0\\0&a^2\end{array}\right),$$

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&a\\a&0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}a^2&0\\0&a^2\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&a^3\\a^3&0\end{array}\right),$$

and so forth.

Comment: OMG I'm so stupid! now it makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

We have
$$
A^2=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&a\\a&0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&a\\a&0\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}a^2&0\\0&a^2\end{array}\right)=a^2I_2
$$
so it's simple to see that 
$$A^k=a^kI_2\;\text{if $k$ is even and}\; A^k=a^{k-1} A\;\text{if $k$ is odd}$$
so
$$\exp(A)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{A^k}{k!}=\sum_{p=0}^\infty\frac{A^{2p}}{(2p)!}+\sum_{p=0}^\infty\frac{A^{2p+1}}{(2p+1)!}= \left(\sum_{p=0}^\infty\frac{a^{2p}}{(2p)!}\right)I_2+\left(\sum_{p=0}^\infty\frac{a^{2p}}{(2p+1)!}\right)A\\=\cosh(a)I_2+\frac{1}{a}\sinh(a)A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}\cosh(a)&\sinh(a)\\\sinh(a)&\cosh(a)\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: This is also great answer, thanks. I got why I would get the sines and cosines, but I forgot how to multiply o.o